# SQL CLR Rights: Call Stored Procedure in CLR Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sqlclr

I have written a (private) stored procedure in T-SQL that is not visible for the user. He has no execute permissions.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEntries]
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM sometable
END
```

Then I wrote a CLR stored procedure, for which the user has the execute permissions. This stored procedure calls my private procedure.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = "context connection=true";
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("exec dbo.[GetEntries] ", conn);
...
```

If I call the public CLR stored procedure, an error occured that I have no rights to call the private stored procedure. I think this is because my connection string is "context connection=true" so the stored procedure is in the user context (user connection).

When I write a public (user visible) T-SQL stored procedure, which calls the private stored procedure, I can execute this stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].TSQLPublicSP
AS
BEGIN
    Exec  dbo.[GetEntries]
END
```

So my question is, how can I set the connection string in the SQL-CLR stored procedure like the connection it is from the T-SQL stored procedure. I don't want to set the databasename in the SQL-CLR connection string. It would be ok for me if I could get the database name form the `SqlContext`:

```
SqlConnection("server=LOCALHOST;integrated security=yes;database=" &
  SqlContext.???CurrentDatabase???)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `Context Connection` is in the security context of the caller (or of the User specified in the `EXECUTE AS` clause of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement, but the default is `EXECUTE AS CALLER`).

The reason that the behavior is different between the SQLCLR stored procedure and the T-SQL stored procedure is:

- The T-SQL stored procedure is making use of ownership chaining to imply permissions on related objects of the same owner as the code being executed.
- The SQLCLR stored procedure is effectively submitting Dynamic SQL (as there is no way to pre-compile code within SQLCLR objects) which breaks ownership chaining.

If you want special permissions, then you need to use module signing as follows:

1. Create a Certificate or Asymmetric Key in this Database
2. Create a User from the Certificate or Asymmetric Key
3. Grant `EXECUTE` permission on the "hidden" stored procedure to the Cert-based or Key-based User
4. Sign the non-"hidden" stored procedure (doesn't matter if the visible one is T-SQL or SQLCLR) using `ADD SIGNATURE`.
5. If you ever make any changes to the Assembly that contains the method for this SQLCLR stored procedure, you will need to re-apply the `ADD SIGNATURE`